# Apache Camel consumes() accepts invalid JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-camel

I have a RESTful endpoint to create a user:

```json
POST /users/new

{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe"
}
```

Camel handles the request via `consumes()` and magically (with the help of Jackson?) transforms keys of the JSON object into message headers, which I access to store the user.

```java
this.restConfiguration()
    .component("netty4-http")
    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
    .contextPath("/").port(AbstractRestRoute.PORT)
    .enableCORS(true)
    .corsAllowCredentials(true)
    .corsHeaderProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");

this.rest.("/users")
    .post("/new")
        .consumes("application/json")
        .produces("application/json")
        .to("direct:rest:newuser");
```

This works as expected. However, one client managed to pass two users objects to the endpoint like this:

```json
POST /users/new

{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe"
}
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jane Doe"
}
```

I would expect Camel to throw a JSON parsing error here.

But: It turns out, the app serves the request (!) and silently ignores the second object. So the request produces the same result as the one above.

Can I put Camel into strict JSON parsing mode to throw an error here?

Comment: Assuming the parser is using streaming-json, then it would only look for the first pair of open-close brackets, and ignore the rest of the payload. But also, the double-quote should throw an error, yes

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the config of the Jackson mapper that is used internally by Camel for the binding.

Have a try with the "json.in.*" properties to enable/disable some Jackson settings.
There is maybe one to be more strict ?

```
restConfiguration().component("...") 
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
            .dataFormatProperty("json.in.disableFeatures", "FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE")
            .dataFormatProperty("json.in.enableFeatures", "FAIL_ON_NUMBERS_FOR_ENUMS,USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS");
```